# Android ListView item not clickable after I add button

Tags: android, listview

Below layout is for individual item in `ListView`. I use custom cursor adapter to populate. I do handle `onItemClick` and it works. But as soon as I add Button inside layout - `onItemClick` no longer fired. How do I make whole row register `onItemClick` and at the same time handle Button `onClick`?

I want to place button (below commented in XML) but I want to handle click on list as well..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_ordinal" style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black" android:textColor="@color/blue_end"/>
    <ImageView
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:id="@+id/iv_thumb"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"          />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_fileGId" style="@style/MyTextViewLabel.Black" android:textColor="@color/blue_end"/>
    <!--<Button-->
        <!--style="@style/MyClearButton"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/bt_delete"-->
        <!--android:text="DELETE"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="50dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:onClick="deleteScannedItemButtonClick"/>-->


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You could try to set the onClickListener to the LinearLayout.

Comment: add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" ` to the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do one thing..do focus able false to the button.
After that in your adapter::

Add One Interface ::

```
 public interface ClickListener{
    void onBtnClicked(int position);
    void onRowClicked(int position);
}
```

After that perform click event of both row & the button like :::

```
 holder.MyClearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onBtnClicked(position);
        }
    });
    holder.convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onRowClicked(position);
        }
    });
```

Where `mListener` will be object of the `ClickListener` that you will pass in the constructor of the adapter while initialize ..

So, that you can get two method in the activity/fragment for those individually..with the help of that position params in the methods..you can get that value of that row item..

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this line to your button in xml file:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

The problem is the Button take the focus from the view group (the item row) it is in. This means that when you click each row it is always the Button that captures the event but as it is outside of its screen area, the event is discarded. Therefore you need to prevent the Button to capture the focus.